# Sharepoint Groups : all users (membership) vs custom built groups

Tags: sharepoint-online

I don't know if this had been answered already, but here's my case : I have a Sharepoint site and some subsites are meant to be shared with external people.
However I don't want those external people to see the root site.

One of my colleagues created an AD account for this and we gave it a O365 license so it has access to the Sharepoint as well.

Since I gave read access to the "all users (membership)" account on the root site, this external account also has access to it, but I don't want this.

So my question is : Would it be better to get rid of the "all users (membership)" and build new groups with all the users who have access to the Sharepoint ?
I'd say it's definitely better but I would need to update it every time a new person arrive in the company. I've started doing it for a few cases, but the update is what takes a lot of time.

We use Sharepoint Online.

Any suggestion is gladly welcome. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It will all depend on the configuration of the information architecture. IF your root site is driving navigation the users will need to have access to part of the site otherwise subsites will not work correctly. Try to give the "all users (membership)" the Limited access to root site (you will need to create that permission level as you cannot use default one), and then give the "all users" access as readers/contributors to subsites. For me Best Practice if you need give access to external users would be using a separate site collection.

Comment: Well, not necessarily. I have another way to work with the external users which is the following : I create Microsoft accounts on Outlook.com and share the subsite to access. It works and when the account tries to access the root site, it says "access denied" which is perfect. So I could also do this way for the newly created account I was talking about, but I was wondering what the best practice is.